# Where do the variables in template inheritance come from?

Tags: python, django, templates, inheritance, view

So based on what I've read from template inheritance, say you have

```
base.html
content.html
content_view.py
```

and there is a function in content_view.py whose template_name="content.html" and content.html extends base.html.  So the locals() which is returned by the funnction in content_view.py is passed into content.html, and since content.html extends base.html, locals() is also passed into base.html.

First of all is this correct?

Second, is there a way to pass more variables into base.html that were not initialized by the function in content_view.py?

Third, is the flow of info always: urls.py -> views.py -> templates, is it possible for urls.py -> views.py -> templates -> views.py -> templates? If, yes, how do you code the redirect?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Actually this question isn't template inheritance specific as the variables available in the template are the same, no matter if you inheritance or not...

Answer (score 0):

> First of all is this correct?

No, `locals()` are not passed to the template from the view.

The variables which are passed to the template are specified in the `dictionary` argument when calling `render` or [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response), adding some more data from [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).  You can also later use a [custom built template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context) to add more variables to the context.

Comment: I meant the view function would return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request)) when i said locals() is passed to the template from the view, when a variable in the template matches a variable in locals() django magic happens, isn't this passing the locals() from view to template?

Comment: If you pass `locals()` you will get `locals()` in your template.  To add more stuff, you can import it to your views module and add it to the dictionary, or use context processors or custom template tags.